# How do I write a Mockito ArgumentMatcher to verify that each element of a set is used

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I need to verify that a given method is called N times, and that every element of a given list is passed as argument. How can I do that using Mockito?

Say I have a method that adds elements to a list:

```
public void addElementsToList(List<String> theList, List<String> theElements) {
   for(String element : theElements) {
      theList.add(element);
   }
}
```

The test should verify that if the `addElementsToList` method is called, each element is added exactly once (but I don't care about the order).

```
@Test
public testAddElements() {
    List<String> list = mock(List.class);
    List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    addElementsToList(list, elements);
    Mockito.verify(list, times(3))
           .add(ArgumentMatchers.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<String>() {
             Set<String> expected = new HashSet<>(elements);
             @Override
             public boolean matches(String argument) {
               return expected.remove(argument);
             }
           }));
}
```

When I run this test, it fails with the message that there have been no interactions with the mock:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooLittleActualInvocations: 
list.add(<custom argument matcher>);
Wanted 3 times:
-> at my.test.package.TestClass.testAddElements(TestClass.java:100)
But was 0 times.
```

When I change the ArgumentMatcher.matches method to simply check that the `expected` set contains the argument, then the test succeeds:

```
             @Override
             public boolean matches(String argument) {
               return expected.contains(argument);
             }
```

Obviously, this test would also succeed if the same argument would be passed multiple times.

**How do I check that a method is called exactly once for each element?**

Comment: Why not just call `verify` in a loop, one time for each element in `elements`?

Comment: @JeffBowman You're right, that does what I want. Seems like I was overthinking it, not realizing that `verify` by default doesn't care about the order. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to skip matcher usage and just ensure that you make one call to `verify` for each set element. Mockito doesn't check order unless you opt in with [`inOrder`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InOrder.html).

```java
for (String element : elements) {
  verify(list).add(element);
}
```

(Side note: Don't mock Collections like Lists outside of toy or example problems.)